# linked-list type comes from string in java

Tags: java, types, linked-list

Is there any way to create a linked-list which type is comes from a string in java. Such that;

```
String str = "Integer"
.... some process with str ...
LinkedList<resultOfProcess> lnklst = new LinkedList<resultOfProcess>();
// equals to LinkedList<Integer> lnklst = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Comment: You can create a linked list of whatever type you want.

Comment: You mean like...`List<String> lnkLst = new LinkedList<String>();`?

Comment: Due to type erasure, the question doesn't make a whole lot of sense as it stands. Could you give some code examples of what you intend to do with `lnklst` once you've created it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Dig more to [Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your result of process is either a number or a string or some kind of data.

So identify the resulting data, if the result is a string, then define as follows

LinkedList resultOfProcessing = new LinkedList();

Answer (score 0):

1) As you already know, you definitely want a generic linked list (you want "List<>", instead of "List").

2) As you also probably know (or at least guessed), since Java is a strongly-typed language, generics are *compile time*.  You need to "declare" all your types up-front.

.... soooooo ....

3) If you want one list, and you want the stuff in that list to be assigned at runtime, then...

4)  Perhaps the best solution is to define some class (or interface) that has a "resultOfProcess" method:

```
 List<MyClassThatDoesThePrcess> myList = new List<MyClassThatDoesThePrcess>();
```

IMHO...